# Background images fit to screen

Tags: css, reactjs

`Hello i'm new to react and wanted to help for my below code home.js code:`

I'm trying to use image as a background to my page, but i'm unable to make it fit the widow size, i tried using background-repeat as no-repeat, backgrond-image  as cover etc.

Comment: CSS code for my query above

Comment: instead of adding information in comments, please edit your question.

Comment: Please take the [tour] and read [ask]. You can always edit your question to include debugging details in form of a [repro]. A comment is the wrong way to do it.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your container is exact size that you expect
and use `background-size: cover;` in css

see more on [background-size](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-size)